# How to read and write URI type using sharedPreferences

Tags: android

Actually I want to know, how can I read and write URI using `sharedPreferences`. I mean to say that suppose I have an int value, e.g.:

```
int x = 10;
```

**Then for write date using `sharedPrferences` I used following code**

```
SharedPreferences preferencesWrite  = getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = preferencesWrite.edit();

editor.putInt("value", x);

editor.commit();
```

**And similarly for reading data code I used is**

```
x = preferencesRead.getInt("value", 0);
```

**Now if I declared** `Uri calenEvent;`
Then how can I read and write it to the register? If anyone knows, please help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covert URI to string

```
String uriStr = uri.toString();
```

You can save this string in SharedPreference easily.

and later reconstruct URI from the string

```
URI uri = new URI(uriString);
```